# Instance variable not initialised with constructor c#

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

I am learning how to use OOP, and I had an exercise which I need to create a class, initialise its variables with a constructor, and change the value of a field using properties (get, set). So basically pressing a button would take the value out of a textbox, and set it with the property. When I tried to compile I had a NullReference Error on my instance variable `private Bankrekening bankrekening`, who is supposedly null, but I don't understand why as I initialised it in a constructor. Can anyone help me out on this?

Winform Code:

```
namepace Bankrekening

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Bankrekening bankrekening;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Bankrekening bankrekening = new Bankrekening();


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bankrekening.rekening = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(bankrekening.rekening);

    }
}
}
```

Class code:

```
namespace Bankrekening
{
class Bankrekening
{
    private int saldo;

    public int rekening
    {
        get
        {
            return saldo;
        }
        set
        {
            saldo = value;
        }
    }


    public Bankrekening()
    {
        saldo=100;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
Bankrekening bankrekening = new Bankrekening();
```

do this:

```
bankrekening = new Bankrekening();
```

You have already declared the variable globally at the class level, but the former is declaring it as a separate local method-level variable.  Because of scoping rules, any usage of that variable within the method will refer to the local variable rather than the global one, unless you use `this.bankrekening`.

Note, for simple cases you may prefer to declare *and* assign in one statement (at the class level) and leave it out of the constructor entirely:

```
private Bankrekening bankrekening = new Bankrekening();
```

Comment: Oh my god thanks, I knew it was something as stupid as this. It got me confused as in class we learned the first method, whilst the book uses the second, I mixed those up. Thank a lot, will mark as answer in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You declare a new **local** variable in the constructor although you use the same name!

By writing the format:

```
Type VariableName = new Type():
```

You create a brand new variable in the constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Bankrekening bankrekening = new Bankrekening();
}
```

This variable is only of local scope and is not the same as at the scope of the class!

Solution: remove the type declaration and the compiler will initialize the right variable:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    bankrekening = new Bankrekening();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are initialising bankrekening twice.

try this:

```
private Bankrekening bankrekening;



public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    bankrekening = new Bankrekening();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining totally new local  variable with same name `bankrekening`. That's why constructor parameter will not intialize the class member `bankrekening`.

Change the form constructor as following. 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.bankrekening = new Bankrekening();
    }

This should resolve your issue.